# 'Cordova/CDVUIWebViewDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, cordova, html-framework-7

I just update cordova to version 10.0.0 and mi xcode is on version 11.3.1 now when I try to build my app I'm getting this error.

'Cordova/CDVUIWebViewDelegate.h' file not found

I don't know how to set the path to this file or fix this error. Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have something depending on `UIWebView` which is deprecated and will not be accepted by Apple when publishing to the App store. I'd make sure `cordova-ios` is up to date (should be version 6), and if you're using `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`, make sure that's also up to date.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue while running `cordova build ios`, I tried upgrading the `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` but and `cordova-ios` but no luck. Please share the solution if you were able to solve the issue.

Comment: Same problem here. I tried to update the plugin but nothing. Cordova CLI 10.0.0 and cordova-ios 6.2.0

Answer (score 4):

Try this in console inside folder with your project:

```sh
rm -rf platforms plugins package-lock.json node_modules
npm install
cordova prepare
```

I had linking problems in Xcode and fix it only by this way (sick!).
Someones recommends this way:

```sh
npm install -g cordova
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: I had to delete this plugin completely in order to continue..

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. I have no idea what to do